# Any one can help me to get the answer of this integral?

Tags: integration

$g$ has an exponential distribution with rate parameter $m>0$. ${\rm Pr}(g)=m e^{-mg}$.

Compute $E[g^{2/a}]=$ where $a$ is a constant.

So I expanded it as $m \int_0^\infty g^{2/a}  e^{-mg} dg =$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Substitute $u=mg$ and this will be recognized as a Gamma function expression.